# Can Bunker's Grenade Launcher be used on the same target 3 times?

Tags: sentinels-of-the-multiverse

Bunker's Grenade Launcher power says "Deal 2 damage to a target, may deal 2 damage to another target, may deal 1 damage to another target." Does that imply that each target would have to be unique? Or could it hit the same target multiple times since it doesn't say a DIFFERENT target.

I always played it as 3 different targets, but I'm wondering if the card is intended to give the option to be like a card that reads "Deal 1 target 1 melee damage and 1 fire damage" OR you can split that damage up among multiple target.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No, you must select different targets for each set of damage.**

In the [Sentinels of the Multiverse app](http://sentinelsdigital.com/buysotm.html) developed by Handelabra Studio in cooperation with Greater Than Games, playing Grenade Launcher asks you to select a target for each instance of dealing damage and does not give you the option for selecting the same target(s).

This matches the usual definition of "another". From dictionary.reference.com:

> **Another** (adj):
>   1.
>   being one more or more of the same; further; additional:
>   another piece of cake.
>   2.
>   different; distinct; of a different period, place, or kind:
>   at another time; another man.
>   3.
>   very similar to; of the same kind or category as:
>   What we need today is another Thomas Jefferson.

In general, Sentinels of the Multiverse cards are very literal in their instructions: if it were intended to have an OR, it would have an OR.

Comment: If it could do damage to the same target it would say do one target damage and then do one target damage. Argent Adept has a card like that and you can hit the same target twice on the mobile app.

Comment: The computerized version has shown me all kinds of cards I was doing wrong in meatspace.  It's been very handy for that.

Comment: If the same target was allowed, it would be written like Chrono-Ranger's *Terrible Tech-Strike*: "Chrono-Ranger deals 1 target 2 melee damage. Chrono-Ranger deals 1 target 1 projectile damage." Note how it repeats the phrase "Chrono-Ranger deals 1 target" rather than mentioning another target, meaning it can be the same target if desired.

Answer (score 0):

> "Deal 1 target 1 melee damage and 1 fire damage" OR you can split that damage up among multiple target.

For the record. I'm fairly certain a card with this reading would require one taget to recieve the melee and fire damage. You are not allowed to split it up into two targets.